# didReceiveMemoryWarning and re-built instance variable equality checking

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiview-hierarchy

I'm going through my iOS app, using "Simulate Memory Warning" as my hammer of justice, and it's causing some unexpected problems (naturally). But this is one problem that has me stumped: objects are seemingly no longer equal.

Say my view controller (we'll name it `VCBob`) has…

- two separate custom `UIViews` as subviews (let's name those views `viewA` and `viewB`)

  - each with their own `UICollectionView` exposed as the property `collectionView` (these `UICollectionViews` use `VCBob` as their `delegates`)
- a `UIButton` that, when pressed, pushes some other view controller (an otherwise insignificant one) on to the stack

So I tap on the `UIButton` and here comes the insignificant view controller. I fire off the "Simulate Memory Warning" option, and `VCBob` is programmed to ditch `viewA` and `viewB` inside of `-didReceiveMemoryWarning`, since they are being totally recreated and re-inserted into the view hierarchy on `viewWillAppear` (so long as they're `nil` at the time of `viewWillAppear`). Here's that implementation in `VCBob`:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    BOOL hasSuperview = self.view.superview != nil;
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if (!hasSuperview) {
        _viewA = nil;
        _viewB = nil;
    }
}
```

I then tap the back button in the navigation bar, and `VCBob` comes back into play. The two custom `UIViews` are still there, and their respective `UICollectionViews` are loaded with content. When I tap on one of the `UICollectionViewCells` in either of the collection views, the `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method gets called on `VCBob`; so far, so good. That implementation looks like this.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (collectionView == self.viewA.collectionView) {
        NSLog(@"Do something here!");
    } else if (collectionView == self.viewB.collectionView) {
        NSLog(@"Do something else here!");
    }
}
```

The problem is *nothing happens* — nothing gets logged. Both of those `if` conditions evaluate to false. Why is that? I kinda seem to think I might be doing bad things in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Should I not be disposing of views there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `_viewA` is in a view hierarchy, it is retained by its superview, so doing `_viewA = nil` will not release it, and it will still be there when the `viewWillAppear` method gets fired.

Then, in your `viewWillAppear` you are adding a "duplicate" of your `viewA`, with its own collectionView inside, placed just over the original one: you see one view, but in truth they are two views overlapped.

So, you should just add a `removeFromSuperview` call in your `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method to get rid of this

The same happens for `viewB`.

Comment: You came to the exact conclusion I did, and posted it a split-second after I posted mine. But since you're not me, I'll give you the answer credit!

Comment: Ahaha thank you :) writing in english takes me too much time, I have to double-check every word I type.. if I could answer in italian I would be much faster :)

Comment: I'd like to think that if I could read Italian, I'd be a much better person, too. Thanks, Alessandro! (And by the way, your English is quite good.)

Answer (score 0):

Rats, I think I figured it out. I was disposing of my views in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` without removing them from the superview first. The `UIView` that I had in place was evidently still retaining instances of my stale objects, even though I had `nil`-ed them out.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    BOOL hasSuperview = self.view.superview != nil;
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if (!hasSuperview) {
        [_viewA removeFromSuperview];
        _viewA = nil;
        [_viewB removeFromSuperview];
        _viewB = nil;
    }
}
```